# so much so that

Tags: adverbial-phrases

I want to know if I understand the correct way to use "so much so that".

Can one say:

> a. I did a lot for them, **so much so that** they've hung a photo of me in their office.
>
> b. Tom was hard-working, **so much so that** we decided to hire him permanently.
>
> c. Harry wasn't hard-working, **so much so that** we decided to let him go.

Answer (score 2):

At first sight these all look OK, but if you consider that the second "so" refers back to the first clause:

a. is saying "I did so much of a lot for them", which is not quite right. In that case you can drop the second so and get "I did a lot for them: so much that ..."

b. passes that test; I see nothing wrong with it at all.

c. fails, in my view. The concept of so much not hard working is again not quite right. How about "Harry wasn't hard working, to the extent that ..."

Answer (score 0):

- I have done so much for them that they have hung a photo of me in their office
- Tom was so hard working we decided to hire him.
- Harry wasn't hard working, so we decided to let him go."

*So much so that* uses unnecessary words.

Comment: __Note:__ you are changing the tense of "do" in the first sentence.